# Launching finder from python

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7

I wish to input a subfolder name into terminal and have a script launch it in finder.
This is my code:

```
import sys
import os

fullname='/home/ash/caffe/examples/imagenet/train_rest/'+str(sys.argv[1])

os.system(gnome-open fullname)
```

However it appears that 'gnome-open' only accepts a path in the traditional /path/to/file format. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: instead of `gnome-open` you should probably use `xdg-open`. It's the same of `gnome-open` except that it also works on other DEs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't use `os.system()` at all. it is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), really, really old-fashioned and discouraged to use any more.

Instead use either [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) or [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-open", '/home/ash/caffe/examples/imagenet/train_rest/'+sys.argv[1]])
# or:
subprocess.call(['gnome-open', '/home/ash/caffe/examples/imagenet/train_rest/'+sys.argv[1]])
```

Also:

No need to use `str(sys.argv[1]`, just `sys.argv[1]`.

#### Note

Probably no need to say, but if your argument (-directory) includes names with spaces, use quotes, e.g.

```
python <script> '/path/with/name with spaces'
```